# Add image behind scatter subplot independent of scatter points axes

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to add an image behind each subplot of my scatter plot figure. I want my image to take up all the subplot space. But I do not want to map my scatter points onto the image: That is, I want the axes of my scatter points to be independent to that of the image.

When I simply use `imread()` and `implot()` while making a subplot to insert the image, like so:

```
im = plt.imread("/Users/mac/Desktop/image.jpeg")
two = plt.subplot(222)
implot = plt.imshow(im)
plt.title('4-8 Hz')
plt.scatter(X,Y, s=100, marker ='o', c=AveragedHursts4to8, cmap = cm.plasma)
plt.colorbar()
two.axis('off')
```

I get the right-most image down below, where, clearly, the image axes and scatter points axes are shared.

I tried to use the `twiny()` function to make a new set of axes for the image, with the image set as the first axes and the second axes set to the scatter points, like so:

```
onetwin = plt.subplot(221)
plt.title('1-4 Hz')
implot = plt.imshow(im, zorder=1)
onetwin.axis('off')
one = onetwin.twiny()
plt.scatter(X,Y, s=100, marker ='o', c=AveragedHursts1to4, cmap = cm.plasma, zorder = 2)
plt.colorbar()
one.axis('off')
```

There I get the leftmost image, where the scatter points are squished on the y axis and the image, for some reason, has been shrunk.

And when I switch the ordering of the creation of the axes for twiny, the image takes up the whole subplot and the scatter points do not show at all.

Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to leave the points' positions untouched and scale the background image accordingly. One can use the `extent` keyword to `imshow` for that purpose.

In the example below I plot some random points on four different scales. Each time the image is scaled to the scatterplot's dimensions using the extent keyword.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(8*8).reshape((8,8))
image = plt.imread("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/EU_flag_square.PNG")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(11,3.8))

for i in range(len(ax)):
    ax[i].scatter(x[2*i,:]*10**(i-1), x[2*i+1,:]*10**(i-1), c="#ffcc00", marker="*", s=280, edgecolors='none')
    xlim = ax[i].get_xlim()
    ylim = ax[i].get_ylim()
    mini = min(xlim[0],ylim[0])
    maxi = max(xlim[1],ylim[1])
    ax[i].imshow(image, extent=[mini, maxi, mini, maxi])
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, fastest solution I came up with is to solve for x and y in:

largest_x_coodinate_value(x) = x_dimension of image_in_pixels

largest_y_coordinate_value(y) = y_dimension_of_image_in_pixels

And then do vectorized multiplication over the numpy arrays containing the X and Y coordinates with those calculated x,y values, effectively scaling the coordinates to the size of the image.

[image]